# can there be two js files in main dir of mozilla addon? and can they both communicate with each other?

Tags: firefox-addon-sdk

I have created two separate add ons. One for getting input from the user and storing in simple-storage. In the other one the actual add on function. Both work fine. But when i merge these both main add on code in to a single main code they didn't work. So i wonder whether there can be two js files in "main" add on directory and is communication possible between them?I need one of the js in main directory to be able to access the simple-storage of the other js in the same main directory.

Answer (score 0):

I'm really not sure what your overall goal is, please provide an example for a more specific answer. If you're using the Add-on SDK, only code in main.js will be run, but you can use commonJS modules to implement various features and use require to import them into main.js.

Please see the docs for more information on how the Add-on SDK works:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK